# HOW DO I CALCULATE THE MEAN OF SELECTED COLUMNS?

Tags: r, mean

I have a large dataset. I want to calculate the mean of some of the columns in the data set together. I am not sure how I can use the

> ```
> colMeans ()
> ```

I have only found how to calculate for categories and rows.

Comment: Given the lack of context, have you tried googling the issue; e.g. [here](https://www.programmingr.com/tutorial/colmeans-in-r/)?

Answer (score 1):

Let me take embedded data `iris` in R as an example.

```
colMeans(iris[, 1:3], na.rm=TRUE) # select columns #1~3.
```